# what does “to correct for the fact that” mean? Is the verb “correct” intransitive in here and does it mean “to be aware of?

Tags: meaning

For instance in this context:

> Third, one needs to correct for the fact that vehicles use different types of fuels

Comment: One needs to ***make corrections / adjustments*** (to some observations / data) to accurately take into account the specified fact. That's the first definition in the first dictionary I looked at: ***remove the errors or faults from***. Also more specifically the (scientific) definition #5 there: ***to alter or adjust so as to bring into accordance with a standard or with a required condition***.

Comment: @Yuri: It means more than "to be aware of".

Comment: Before deciding to close a question of this nature one should **correct for** the degree of difficulty in finding the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's an idiom, as the meaning is pretty literal.  You have to *correct* (make a correction) for a particular *fact*.  Examples:

> When drawing maps, [cartographers](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cartographer) have **to correct for the fact** that the Earth is not flat.
>
> If you're plotting a course across water, you must **correct for the fact** that the winds and the currents will often push the boat in a different direction than the one you want to go.

That being said "correct for the fact" can be a little *wordy*.  Often "correct for" is sufficient:

> Third, one needs **to correct for** the different types of fuels vehicles use.
>
> If plotting an ocean course, be sure **to correct for** the wind and the current.

Answer (score 2):

We have the simple transitive verb **to correct** which takes a direct object:

> He corrected the error.

He fixed the error.

We have the intransitive **to correct** which takes as complement a prepositional phrase headed by **for**.  It means "to make adjustments or accommodations, taking {something} into account as a factor".  The {something} is the object of the preposition **for**.

> When shooting an arrow at a very distant target, you must correct for
>   wind speed.

Wind speed must be taken into consideration as a factor when aiming the arrow.

You cannot aim as usual. Your aim must be adjusted, taking the wind into account.

P.S. The {something} can be a longer noun-phrase:

> Before deciding to close a question, moderators should correct for *the
>   fact that online dictionaries might not provide an answer*.